# Why Firefox print css blank?

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I created style document.Document have long data. I use:

`page-break-inside: avoid;`
when print in Section.

I can print in Chrome, Edge but in Firefox look like `page-break-inside: avoid;` 
did't work and when print.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjIZZ.jpg)

The paper should have 4 sheets but It have only 2 sheets and Second page is blank

Comment: My Firefox version 6.2 can use page-break-inside: avoid;

Comment: Can you include relevent code (basic HTML and the CSS) ?

Comment: I use !mportant

Comment: I don't think you should. In most cases `!important` is useless. I may be wrong though, it depends on your code. Also, What is your version of Firefox ?

Comment: ok, I use styled-component in react  **@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0.1in 0.1in; 
  } ** and .Section{  @media print {    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}}

Comment: I create new report(document) in old project..old report use like me page-break but It work in Firefox.

Comment: My Firefox Version is 62.0

Comment: You should put that code in your question, and also include the HTML architecture.

Comment: I found a problem, Thank you for your help. My problem about I use flex in flex in another Browser get flex inside but Firefox get flex outside and flex inside